# Changing a view in the ui router $stateChangeStart event

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a site with a main state and view that can contain a number of sub views for each route.  I'm implementing authentication and I'm using the $stateChangedStart event to check whether a user should be able to see the page.  If the user is not permitted to view the page, I still want them to be redirected, but I want to change the main view to a forbidden view.

In the $stateChangeStart event I have access to the "toState" object which I can then modify the views of.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Here's a plunker to explain: http://plnkr.co/edit/7pvIEQ6e4zitp6ANJJ9h?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that I'm thinking about this the wrong way.  I don't need to intercept the state change event because I'm awlays going to state change to that page anyway.  What I need to do is handle the permissions issue on the page itself.